# Angular 2 - ngIf intercept change attribute

Tags: angular

I'm developing a template with accordion. When I open this accordion, it attribute "aria-expanded" get value true. How I can intercept this using Angular 2? I can do this with jquery but I have to avoid using this atm.
That I need is to know when aria-expanded is true to do something next.
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can bind aria-expanded to a variable on your component and the do what you want with that variable. Post more details if you want an example.

Comment: I have to change an icon css when my bootstrap collapse is open (so when in my accordion aria-expanded=false). So I have to target this value and if it is true my icon need to be green, if is false (so if my accordion is closed) my icon has to be red.

Comment: Who triggers the collapse open/close? Trigger at that point a Boolean like isElementCollapsed=true/false and use it to change the color on your icon. This way you don't need to listen to aria-expaded attribute.